# Crystal Reports how to stop GroupHeader being repeated

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I stop GroupHeader being repeated when KeepTogether forces the group to the next page? I've found a variety of posts around on how to make headers repeat.. not so many on avoiding it.

This is a large report that has been pieced-together (by me, I admit) over time as needs arose.  I group first by one sorting variable, then by another, and then I have several groups on hte same database field.  The reason for several groups with same field is to be able to have show, size and sequence control on a variety of actions. I don't claim it's the best way to do it, just the one I came up with.  The following is a simplified layout

sort1 group1 header

sort2 group2 header 

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

sort2 group2 footer

sort1 group1 footer

Group2 header has Repeat on all pages.  Group3 has KeepTogether selected.  I also have KeepTogether checked for each section and for every subreport, which first happened (against my space-conserving desires) due to footer5 showing near bottom of page, footer4 not showing anywhere(grr), with footer3 on the next page making the MIA 4 easy to not notice.  That all seemed to be working fine.

I'm now adding a feature, and as I hunt for its bugs, discover that header 3 is being repeated when group3 (represented by footer5) is at the end of a page and gets shifted to next page for fit.

I tried to have the headers Suppress on InRepeatGroupHeader, but that did not do as I expected (I seem to remember being disappointed in that function in the past too). I started to try to have simply Copies of group3 header instead of multiple groups, but then I can't select hide for one and show for the other...

I'd be grateful for any ideas to try out. HS

PS.  I also tried using a flag variable to show where had been (increment a numbervar by 1 whenever done a formula), and have hte initializing formula check it before running, and then reset it to zero in the group3 footer.  >> When a group did the jump page thing, I watch the flag go from 0 to 2 to 4.. and then it's suddenly back at zero (at hte spot where it goes from normal behaviour to restarting group process... so I'm guessing it's doing the formulas it finds in group footers even after it's realized it won't fit on one page, and only after that goes on to the next page and redoes the whole group.

PS#2 (answering Siva's question

page 1 start here

sort1 group1 header

sort2 group2 header 

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

>>>page 2 might starts here

*I* would like it to do this

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

ID group3 header - hidden section.  initializing variables

ID group4 header - subreport with nothing shown

>>>and then page 3 might start here

*I* would like it to do this, or at least have something that I can use to suppress all actions in 'repeated' sections

ID group5 header - hidden section. formulas doing math to variables using data from subreport

ID group5 footer - section that shows.  title info about ID, including from variables

ID group4 footer - subreport that shows up with sales info

ID group3 footer - subreport that shows up with components info

Answer (score 0):

Lenghty explanation of the issue to the extent I understand use below solution.

on the `supress` section of `group header3` write below formula.

```
if pagenumber<>1
then true
else false
```

Comment: Except that this is a lengthy report, there are many ID returned, so group3 header is not always on page 1. Unless there is a pagenumber variable that is actually 'group's start page'...

Comment: There is `pagenumber` in special feilds.

Comment: some group3header's first run with a new ID are on page 2, and others on 3 and so on. and hte first run with a new ID does not want to be suppressed.

Comment: new group ID means new group of group1 and group2?